# Convert day, full month, year and country to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to convert the string `18 December 2009 (Sweden)` to `2009-12-18` but I can't figure out how. So I asking you now: how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the full month always in English, or do you expect `18 Januari 2009 (Sweden)`? And is it always going to be Sweden?

Comment: @NullUserException: `18 Januari 2009 (Sweden)` is mixed between different titles. This information comes from imdb.com.

Comment: @ceejayoz: Yes, I have. It only prints `1970-01-01`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are doing there, but judging from the error message you wrote in your comment to JM above, I'd say you are approaching the problem from the wrong end. Quoting:

> Thanks! When I try the function with `$oIMDB->getReleaseDate()` I get following error messages:
>
> > Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message `DateTime::__construct()` [datetime.--construct]: Failed to parse time string (`<time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2009-12-18">18 December 2009</time>`) …

In other words, your `getReleaseDate` returns an XML string that has an attribute `datetime` with the value you are trying to convert the element value to. So, there is no need to convert anything, because the converted value is already there. All you have to do is use [SimpleXml](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) or [DOM](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and access that attribute value, e.g.

```
$time = simplexml_load_string($oIMDB->getReleaseDate());
echo $time['datetime'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use strtotime():

```
<?php
$sdate = '18 December 2009';
$timestamp = strtotime($sdate);
$d = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
echo "$d\n"; // 2009-12-18
```

If your problem is that the '(Sweden)' part is always present, you could just remove that part first:

```
<?php
$sdate = '18 December 2009 (Sweden)';
$sdate = preg_replace('/ \(.*\)$/', '', $sdate);
$timestamp = strtotime($sdate);
$d = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
echo "$d\n"; // 2009-12-18
```

Or with added checking:

```
<?php
$sdate = $oImdb->getReleaseDate();
if ($sdate !== 'n/A') {
    $sdate = preg_replace('/ \(.*\)$/', '', $sdate);
    $timestamp = strtotime($sdate);
    $d = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
} else {
    $d = 'n/a';
}
echo "$d\n"; // 2009-12-18
```

Or use sscanf():

```
<?php
$sdate = '18 December 2009 (Sweden)';
list($day, $month, $year) = sscanf($sdate, '%d %s %d');
$timestamp = strtotime("$day $month $year");
$d = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
echo "$d\n"; // 2009-12-18
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have some problems with the second and third solution (I haven't tried the first solution yet because of the name of the country in the string). The second solution prints correct date if I have exactly as you showed. If I replace `18 December 2009 (Sweden)` with `$oIMDB->getReleaseDate()` it prints `1970-01-01`. The third solution prints `2011-10-09` with $oIMDB->...

Comment: I don't know exactly what `$oIMDB->getReleaseDate()` returns, so I've just worked from your example. If you can give some examples of the sort of dates you're getting back, we should be able to come up with a more general solution. Maybe some dates have different text after the year, so the regular expression isn't matching.

Comment: I use this class: https://github.com/FabianBeiner/PHP-IMDB-Grabber. You can find `$oIMDB->getReleaseDate()` in the `imdb.class.php` file at line 807.

Comment: Is it failing because the returned date is 'n/A' (i.e. not found)?  It might be useful to echo out the return from `$oIMDB->getReleaseDate()` so we can see what it's trying to match against. If the problem is that there's no release date for that film, you can put in an exception (see edited example in main answer).

Comment: Hm, okey. I have tried to remove `return $this->strNotFound;` from the class file, but it returns the same "error" as always - nothing.

Comment: If you remove `return $this->strNotFound;`, then the function will just return `null` if there's no release date. You would then need to check for that response and act accordingly.

Comment: Very true. Unfortunately I don't have the needed knowledge to do that :/ My brain just spinning empty, so to speak, when I try to do anything else than I already have done :)

Answer (score 0):

First use Explode etc to remove the country name an store the Date and Country Name in separate strings, and then use strtotime

```
strtotime("18 December 2009")
strtotime(<String Variable containing date>)
```

It returns a timestamp, you can then use it as you want. [See this for reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Then use [Date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to convert the timestamp to date in the format you want.

Comment: Thanks! `$test = explode(' ', $oIMDB->getReleaseDate()); echo $test[2];` prints `datetime="2009-12-18">18`. The smartest thing to get the date from `datetime=""` is `preg_match`. I'm only a beginner in `preg_match` and i wonder now: how do I get only the date within `datetime=""`?

Comment: Strtotime returns date in a timestamp, use Date to get date in a string from that timestamp, or use getdate to get date in an array from the timestamp

Answer (score 0):

There is also the PHP 5 DateTime object, which will allow you to capture time zones and convert time zones if start using times in addition to the date.

```
<?php
$sdate = '18 December 2009 (Sweden)';
$sdate = preg_replace('/ \(.*\)$/', '', $sdate);
$datetime = new DateTime($sdate, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d');  // 2009-12-18
```

The DateTime object will allow you to manipulate the date without any seconds arithmetic, which can be a reason to use DateTime instead of strtotime().

For example, this would add one month to your original date. Many benefits of the DateTime class.

```
$datetime->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
```

Comment: Thanks! When I try the function with `$oIMDB->getReleaseDate()` I get following error messages: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [datetime.--construct]: Failed to parse time string (<time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2009-12-18">18 December 2009</time>) at position 0 (<): Unexpected character' in ...` and `Exception: DateTime::__construct() [datetime.--construct]: Failed to parse time string (<time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2009-12-18">18 December 2009</time>) at position 0 (<): Unexpected character in ...`

Comment: Make sure whatever you feed into the DateTime constructor is actually '18 December 2009'.  Test with `echo $sdate;` to make sure the string is correct.

Comment: `$sdate` prints `18 December 2009`.

Comment: Looks like you are feeding the entire xml string into the first argument to DateTime::__construct()